# How to play audio from an http data stream in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audio-streaming, http-streaming

I have an audio data stream coming in from a http response. I receive packets of bytes using the **URLSessionDataDelegate** method:

`urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)`

I have successfully played the audio after appending all the data packets into a single Data object, using an `AVAudioPlayer` object and it's `initWithData:` initializer method.

What I really want to do is start audio playback while data is still coming in - *streaming audio* effectively. I haven't seen any answers that seem elegant for this use-case.

Options I've seen are:

1. Using the AudioToolbox: Audio File Stream Services & Audio Queues
2. Using the NSStream API, writing to a file and playing audio from that file concurrently

How would I achieve audio streaming playback from the Data packets coming in?

Comment: Have you considered using `AVPlayer` for that?

Comment: I've looked at one or two examples using `AVAssetResouceLoader`, but not deeply. I'm open to solutions with AVPlayer, what would that look like?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use `AVPlayer` of `AVFoundation` framework. Instantiate the playerItem with your URL and pass it the player. Following code will do for you.

```
    let urlString = "your url string"
    guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
        else {
            return
    }
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
    player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.play()
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider `AVPlayer` for your requirement, something like this :

```
import AVKit
var player: AVPlayer?
func audioPlayer() {
    do {
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
         player = AVPlayer(url: URL.init(string: "your url")!)

          //This is for a player screen, if you don't want to show a player screen you comment this part

          let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
          controller.player = player
          controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
          self.addChildViewController(controller)
          let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
          let videoFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 130, width: screenSize.width, height: (screenSize.height - 130) / 2)
          controller.view.frame = videoFrame
          self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
          // till here

          player?.play()
        } catch {
        }
}
```

For more please read this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer